# Is it possible to disable html code error auto fixing feature by wordpress 4.9.1?

Tags: multisite, core

I'm on Wordpress 4.9.1 and there's this new feature that detects HTML error and auto fixes the errors when updating the page. Is it possible to disable this feature? The error is false positive since it's still working as intended.

Note : 
- I'm the super admin and HTML errors seems to not be auto fixed for me. The fix only applies for admins/editors only
- I'm using wordpress multisite

Comment: Do you mean in the plugin/theme editor or the post/page editor? Can you give an example?

Comment: In post/page editor. Nevermind about that though, I played around and decided it can't be disabled. I added `onclick=does something` in-line on an HTML tag and wordpress counts that as an error and it disappears after updating the page. So, I decided to put the function on an external script file and everything's working as intended.

Comment: It's probably better to use *event-based* Javascript and keep the HTML clean of any inline Javascript code.

Comment: You should be able to disable it in your user profile.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution for this referencing this site https://checknotes.wordpress.com/2016/02/06/unfiltered-html-in-wordpress/

Wordpress Multisite only allows unfiltered_html capabilities for super admin, which explains why administrators and editors HTML keeps disappearing. I decided to use 'Unfiltered MU' Wordpress plugin to allow unfiltered_html for admin and editor role